# Navigating to a specific view from appdelegate using xamarin.ios and mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, appdelegate

I am working on a cross platform app using xamarin and MVVMcross.

I want to navigate to Login page when the app is in background for a specific amount of time.
I was successfull in implementing the same in android but wasn't able to find a proper solution in ios for this where MVVMCross is used.

Below is my Android code which is working

Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginView));
var viewModelRequest = new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel));

```
                var serializer = new MvvmCross.Core.Parse.StringDictionary.MvxViewModelRequestCustomTextSerializer();
                intent.PutExtra("MvxLaunchData", serializer.SerializeObject(viewModelRequest));
                StartActivity(intent);
```

I need to implement the same in ios. I know I need to write a similar code like in android in WillEnterForeground method of Appdelegate but wasn't able to find  a proper solution for it anywhere.
Is WillEnterForeground the right place to do this ?

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go one step ahead

```
        var view = (IMvxIosView)UIStoryboard.FromName("Tasks", null).InstantiateViewController("LoginView");            
        var viewController = view.CreateViewControllerFor(viewModelRequest) as UIViewController;
        Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(viewController);
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

Now I am able to get to the login screen when the app comes in foreground again.
But when I click the Login button nothing happens.
Just for more information i am using Storyboards and have overridden CreateIosViewsContainer method of MvxIosSetup in my Setup class.

Any help please as I am relatively very new to ios development?

Comment: Have you created an outlet of the login button?
And then, something like this in ViewDidLoad 
LoginBtn.TouchUpInSide = (obj) => { your code}